# Specify identity file (id_rsa) with rsync

Tags: ssh, rsync

I need to make periodic backups of a directory on a remote server which is a virtual machine hosted by a research organisation. They mandate that access to VMs is through ssh keys, which is all good, except that I can't figure out how to point rsync to the ssh key for this server.

Rsync has no problem if the key file is `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, but when it is something else I get `Permission denied (publickey)`.

With ssh I can specify the identity file with `-i`, but rsync appears to have no such option.

I have also tried temporarily moving the key on the local machine to `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, but that similarly does not work.

**tl;dr**

Can you specify an identity file with rsync?

Comment: Useful also in order to do `sudo rsync`, which doesn't use one's own ssh keys, for some reason.

Comment: @ijoseph Exactly, I use `rsync -aAP "sudo -u user ssh" user@server:dir local_dir` when syncing from cron scripts which run as root

Answer (score 681, accepted):

You can specify the exact ssh command via the '-e' option:

```
rsync -Pav -e "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/somekey" username@hostname:/from/dir/ /to/dir/
```

Many ssh users are unfamiliar with their ~/.ssh/config file. You can specify default settings per host via the config file.

```
Host hostname
    User username
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/somekey
```

In the long run it is best to learn the ~/.ssh/config file.

Comment: Does not help for me to have the IdentityFile in ssh_config. I can "ssh web1" without problems, but when using rsync to web1:... it fails with "Permission denied (publickey)".

Comment: Try turning up verboseness of the ssh transport:   rsync -e 'ssh -vv' web1:/etc/issue /tmp/issue

Comment: I did, log shows it use the correct key but it does not ask me for the passphrase and thus fails (or so it seems to me).

Comment: Ah.  If you are automating this and will not be able to supply a password you will need an additional passwordless ssh key configured at both ends.  If you would like rsync to work without a password in an interactive session you will need to use ssh-agent.

Comment: "remote" is to be replaced with the hostname.
Might seem obvious to some but it wasn't for me because I tried specifying the hostname in the -e option.

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard: Thanks - I rewrote it for what is likely the common scenario.

Comment: Using single tick quotes and ~ I encountered error "Warning: Identity file ~/.ssh/somekey not accessible: No such file or directory." e.g. -e 'ssh -i ~/.ssh/somekey'. Using double quotes and $HOME instead of ~ worked ok. e.g.  -e "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/somekey".  This is on redhat/bash.

Comment: A word of warning with using the -e method. Using rsync on cygwin on windows - using -e cut my copy throughput in half. Using an ssh-agent with a key was much much faster. No idea why.

Comment: Duuuuuuude! the `~/.ssh/config` file - you have opened a new universe for me!

Comment: ~/.ssh/config saved me the day, thanks a lot.

Comment: Better syntax when defining host as `hostid` in .ssh/config: `rsync -e hostid:/path/ /path/`

Comment: If you want to do the opposite - to send from your local machine to the server - you just need to reverse the order like this: `rsync /from/dir/ -Pav -e "ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/somekey" username@hostname:/to/dir/`

Comment: This was not working for me until I used sudo in the ssh command as below `rsync -Pav -e "sudo ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/somekey" username@hostname:/from/dir/ /to/dir/`

Comment: In my case for `~/.ssh/config` to work I had to do `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config`

Comment: or `rsync -avzP -e ...`

Comment: That was awesome.. thank you and rsync

Comment: you're my hero!

Answer (score 26):

This can be done with SSH user config see:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-ssh-config-file-on-linux-unix/
basically edit ~/.ssh/config:

```
$ nano ~/.ssh/config
#Add Hosts below 
Host server1
HostName examplehost.com
User username
Port 22
IdentityFile /path/to/key

$ rsync -e ssh /home/user/directory user@remote.host.net:home/user/directory/
```

This should work for any program using SSH, rsync,

Comment: You can use `rsync -e ssh /home/user/directory server1:home/user/directory/` as well

Answer (score 14):

For me it was sufficient to start the ssh-agent as follows:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add /path/to/mykey
```

See also a longer answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent

Answer (score 4):

FYI:

1) The public key is always in the home directory of the user logging in to remote server i.e. if you login as "backup" it is located at /home/backup/.ssh/authorized_keys. User ID when you login defines the public key used at the destination.

You can choose the user ID when making connection by two different ways:

```
ssh user_id@destination.server
or
ssh -l user_id  destination_server     (<-- that is lower case "L")
```

On the other hand at your end the private key is in a similar way in homedir of user unless you override it like described in Dan's answer.

2) For backup purpose it may be desirable to create a restricted key which is limited to run just one command like "rsync".  There is a good description about that related to "rsnapshot" backup which allows you to remote backup entire server using non privileged user account and "sudo":

["rsnapshot" howto](http://alien.slackbook.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=linux:rsnapshot)

Rsnapshot can easily backup a bunch of remote or local servers making it handy scheduled & centralised backup server.